# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController EXC_BAD_ACCESS collecting emails and phone numbers

Tags: ios, contacts, exc-bad-access, abrecord

I am using an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to collect an array of email addresses and phone numbers from a contact book entry. 90% of the time it works fine but a few testers are reporting crashes. The crash report says it is crashing at CFRelease ... Not sure why considering I believe my code is correct. Take a look:

```
ABProfile *selectedUser = [[ABProfile alloc]init];

ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

NSArray *emailArray;

if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails) > 0) {
    emailArray = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emails);
}

CFRelease(emails);

ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

NSMutableArray *phonesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];

for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:1];

    CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);

    CFStringRef locLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j);
    NSString *phoneLabel =(__bridge_transfer NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel);

    CFRelease(locLabel);

    [dict setValue:phoneLabel forKey:@"label"];
    NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)phoneNumberRef;

    [dict setValue:phoneNumber forKey:@"number"];

    [phonesArray addObject:dict];
}

selectedUser.phones = phonesArray;

CFRelease(phones);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex` can return `NULL` if not found, and `CFRelease(NULL)` will crash. I would cheek to ensure `locLabel` exists before doing anything with it.